# Call to REST API works in CURL but not with Node app

Tags: rest-api, node.js, node-salesforce

I'm trying to make a REST API call to get a list of communities, using Axios from node. Here's the code that is getting called;

```
async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
      console.log(`going to call ${req.user.sfInstanceUrl}/services/data/v49.0/connect/communities`);
      console.log(`actual bearer token: ${req.user.sfAccessToken}`);
      const communitiesResponse = await axios.get(`${req.user.sfInstanceUrl}/services/data/v49.0/connect/communities`, {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.user.sfAccessToken}`
      });
      if (communitiesResponse.status === 200) {
        console.log(`communities response is: ${JSON.stringify(communitiesResponse)}`);
        res.status(200).send(communitiesResponse['communities']);
        } 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
            }
```

now, this endpoint is getting called and I can see that both the instance URL and the access token are set correctly with the logging statements. Axios is returning a 401 Unauthorized error however (boo!)..

When I take this out of the logs and run a cURL statement, the data is returned and i'm authorised. Eg, the cURL statement that works;

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://adams-scv-demo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/connect/communities' --header 'Authorization: Bearer {myValidAuthToken}'
```

i'm confused, sad and afraid at this... wondering what security setting I may have missed in my org to allow this site to call into the API? (the login stuff obviously works though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the axios [docs](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/headers) looks like you are missing the headers object in the request.

Change it to below

```
const communitiesResponse = await axios.get(`${req.user.sfInstanceUrl}/services/data/v49.0/connect/communities`,
      { 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.user.sfAccessToken}`
       }
});
```

Comment: doh! thanks for being my rubber duck :) that should've been really obvious...